# How am I supposed to use Devise and Omniaauth in Database Mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid, omniauth

I did look Ryan Bates episodes to use devise with omniauth. Problem is that I am able to sign up with linkdin. My code

In my user.rb

```
field :provider,   :type => String
     field :uid,   :type => String
      field :name,   :type => String

 #has_many :authentications
   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice("provider", "uid")).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
    end
  end
```

I add this and in my create controller for authentication I did

```
 user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
```

I am succeded to put the value of linkdin in my user database as

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("50b2f4e66d7ab88ac7000003"), "email" : "", "encrypted_password" : "", "sign_in_count" : 0, "provider" : "linkedin", "uid" : "wuBFLcbDyB", "name" : null, "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-11-26T04:49:42.549Z"), "created_at" : ISODate("2012-11-26T04:49:42.549Z") }
```

But as I login from linkdin it does not signup through linkdin else it redirects to

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

How can I login through that linkdin?

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this in your user model

```
validates :username, presence: true
```

Then you must know that linked in does not provide you any username. Since that, to complete your authentication / registration, your user has to add explicitly his username.

Make sure that your registrations_contreoller.rb looks like this

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
  end

private

  def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
      @user.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I did that also . Now i am fetching this problem. If you can give me suggestion then it will make my day.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561140/i-am-using-rails-cast-omniauth-and-i-get-this-error